# Load users by birthday

Tags: c#, .net

I want to know is there a better/easier way to load users by birthday.

I have a User instance, which has properties, including this one:

`public DateTime? BirthDate { get; set; }`

What I want to do is to load that users who has bdays from one date to another:

```
public IEnumerable<User> LoadUsersByBirthday(DateTime from, DateTime into)
```

I don't care about birthday year, for example, if I have 3 users with birthdays:

1. DateTime(1991, 3, 20);
2. DateTime(1990, 4, 25);
3. DateTime(1989, 3, 10);

`LoadUsersByBirthday(new DateTime(2990, 3, 1), new DateTime(3013, 4, 15))` should return 2 users - 1st and 3rd.

My method looks like this:

```
public IEnumerable<User> LoadUsersByBirthday(DateTime from, DateTime into)
    {
        var days = DateTime.DaysInMonth(from.Year, from.Month);

        var u1 = _unit.User.Load(u => ((DateTime) (u.BirthDate)).Month == from.Month
                                      && ((DateTime) (u.BirthDate)).Day >= from.Day
                                      && ((DateTime) (u.BirthDate)).Day <= days);

        var u2 = _unit.User.Load(u => ((DateTime) (u.BirthDate)).Month > from.Month
                                      && ((DateTime) (u.BirthDate)).Month < into.Month);

        var u3 = _unit.User.Load(u => ((DateTime) (u.BirthDate)).Month == into.Month 
                                      && ((DateTime) (u.BirthDate)).Day <= into.Day);

        return u1.Concat(u2).Concat(u3);
    }
```

It works, but is there a better/easier way to do this?

Comment: Actually, I don't think that will work for people born on Feb 29th if the target year isn't a leap year...

Comment: If you do not care about the year, either do not use `DateTime` (which *does* care about the year), or create `DateTime` values with one uniform dummy year before comparing.

Comment: What should happen if the month of `from > into`? E.g. `LoadUsersByBirthday(new DateTime(2990, 12, 1), new DateTime(3013, 1, 15))`?

Comment: @O.R.Mapper I need to know year of my users, I can't skip this. If I will not have a year - I will not be able to know user's age!

Comment: @O.R.Mapper It's not possible to ignore the year, since you have to take leap years into account for people born on 29th Feb.

Comment: fixed my answer. you need to create new DateTime with equal year for all compared elements

Comment: @MatthewWatson: In that case, pick a leap year as the uniform year.

Comment: @Art713: You do not need (want) to know the year during the comparison - at least that is what your text "I don't care about birthday year" suggests.

Comment: @O.R.Mapper I don't care about year in this method, but I do need year at my project!

Comment: @Art713: Yes, I am aware of that. Still, you can ignore the year in the portion of code where you compare the dates.

Comment: @O.R.Mapper That's what i'm doing =)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think this should work:

```
public IEnumerable<User> UsersByBirthday(IEnumerable<User> users, DateTime from, DateTime to)
{
    var fromNormalized = NormalizeDate(from);
    var intoNormalized = NormalizeDate(into);

    return users.Where(u => fromNormalized <= NormalizeDate(u.BirthDate) && NormalizeDate(u.BirthDate) <= intoNormalized);
}

public int NormalizeDate(DateTime date)
{
    return date.Month * 100 + date.Day;
}
```

The `NormalizeDate()` method returns an integer value representing the month and day that is easy to compare with. For September 3 it returns 903, for April 24 it returns 424.

No error handling for if `from > to`.

Comment: This also fails for people born on a leap day (feb 29th). In leap years their birthdays are on Feb 29th; on other years their birthdays are on March 1st.

Comment: I didn't understand this. What does NormalizeDate return?

Comment: @MatthewWatson: Is that actually well defined? I would have said if you are asking if it was in the range 1st March - 10th March the answer would be no but also if you asked if it was in the range 1st Feb to 28th Feb the answer would be no. It sounds like its something to consider but also something to be left to personal choice (eg is 1st March better than 28th Feb?)

Comment: @Art713 I added a description of `NormalizeDate` to the answer.

Comment: @MatthewWatson I agree with Chris. But I guess it is up to OP to decide.

Comment: @Chris There are legal definitions for this, because the law needs to know when someone is 18 for the purposes of voting and buying alcohol and so on. In the UK, someone born on Feb 29th has their birthday on March 1st on non leap years, according to the actual law. But it's different for different countries. It's an annoying problem.

Comment: @MatthewWatson Do these legal definitions apply to OP's problem domain?

Comment: @TorbjörnKalin They might do, but regardless the "leap day birthday" problem must be considered, whichever way it goes.

Answer (score 3):

This was harder to solve than expected, due to the problems caused by leap years and people who's birthdays are actually on a leap day.

Finally, I remembered I had already a method that calculates someone's age in years accurately, accounting for leap years and birthdays that occur on a leap year.

Given such a method, it's trivial to determine if someone has a birthday give a range of dates:

First, calculate their age one day *BEFORE* the start of the range.
Next, calculate their age at the end of the range.

If the calculated ages differ, then they must have had a birthday in the specified range.

Putting it all together:

```
public IEnumerable<User> UsersByBirthday(IEnumerable<User> users, DateTime from, DateTime to)
{
    if (to < from)
        throw new ArgumentException("'from' must be at or before 'to'.");

    return users.Where(user => IsBirthdayInRange(user.BirthDate, from, to));
}

public bool IsBirthdayInRange(DateTime birthday, DateTime from, DateTime to)
{
    if (to < from)
        throw new ArgumentException("'from' must be at or before 'to'.");

    if (birthday > from)
        throw new ArgumentException("'from' must be after 'birthday'");

    return AgeInYears(birthday, from.AddDays(-1)) < AgeInYears(birthday, to);
}

/// <summary>Returns a person's age in years, accounting for leap years.</summary>

public static int AgeInYears(DateTime birthday, DateTime today)
{
    // See here for why this works:
    // http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/ba4a98af-aab3-4c59-bdee-611334e502f2/calculate-age-with-a-single-line-of-code-c

    return ((today.Year - birthday.Year) * 372 + (today.Month - birthday.Month) * 31 + (today.Day - birthday.Day)) / 372;
}
```

Here's a little test for a leap day birthday:

```
DateTime test = new DateTime(2004, 2, 29); // Leap day.

var start = new DateTime(2005, 3, 1);
var end = new DateTime(2005, 6, 7);

Console.WriteLine(IsBirthdayInRange(test, start, end));
```

---

Using your `_unit.User.Load()`:

```
public IEnumerable<User> LoadUsersByBirthday(DateTime from, DateTime into)
{
    return _unit.User.Load(u => IsBirthdayInRange(u.Birthdate, from, into));
}
```

---

[EDIT]

There are two possibilities for handling a leap day birthday in a non-leap year: Treat it as Feb 28th, or treat it as Mar 1st.

The code above treats it as Mar 1st (as per UK regulations). If you want to parameterise the handling, you can add a `leapDayMapsToFeb28` parameter to `IsBirthdayInRange()` as follows:

```
public bool IsBirthdayInRange(DateTime birthday, DateTime from, DateTime to, bool leapDayMapsToFeb28)
{
    if (to < from)
        throw new ArgumentException("'from' must be at or before 'to'.");

    if (birthday > from)
        throw new ArgumentException("'from' must be after 'birthday'");

    if (leapDayMapsToFeb28 && (birthday.Month == 2) && (birthday.Day == 29) && !DateTime.IsLeapYear(from.Year))
        birthday = new DateTime(birthday.Year, birthday.Month, 28);

    return AgeInYears(birthday, from.AddDays(-1)) < AgeInYears(birthday, to);
}
```

Comment: You was right about leap years, but I don't have to throw an exceptions, `LoadUsersByBirthday(DateTime from, DateTime into)` method has particular signature, where i must to give to the method only 2 dates, and method should returns users as was described before.

Comment: @Art713 Your question didn't define what _unit.User.Load() does, so I have provided a general solution which will work with any sequence of Users. You should easily be able to plug in your user sequence.

Comment: _unit.User.Load(predicate) just gives me users that satisfy the predicate

Comment: @Art713 In that case you could just use the `IsBirthdayInRange` predicate that I wrote (I appended to my answer what I think it would look like)

Comment: @Art713 Also note that I removed the (erroneous) requirement that the from and to years are the same.

Answer (score 1):

You can convert DateTime to Ticks and compare that.

Something like that code(havent VS near so can be syntax errors)

```
   DateTime from=new DateTime(...); 
   DateTime into=new DateTime(...); 

   IList<User> allUsers=...
```

fixed:

```
IList<User> foundedUsers=allUsers.Where(user=> (new DateTime(1900, user.Birthday.Month,  user.Birthday.Day)>new DateTime(1900,from.Month,from,Day)) && ...).ToList();
```

Comment: That doesn't ignore the year. This will not work for the OP's data.

Comment: fixed code. now will be ignore. but i think will be problems leap years if set fixed year as not leap year

Comment: Assuming that existing data is valid your code is better, it will only look at month and day and 1900 is a leap year.

Answer (score 1):

Let's say the first day is birthday1(y1, m1, d1), the second day is birthday2(y2, m2, d2), then you can use this:

```
diff = 31 * (m2 - m1) + (d2 - d1)
```

Because `-31 < d2 - d1 < 31`, so if `m2 - m1 > 0`, then no matter what d2 or d1 is, the result is diff > 0; it is the same when `m2 - m1 < 0`, `diff < 0`; when `m2 == m1`, diff's value range depands only on d2 and d1. In fact, 31 can be replace by any number greater 31, like 32.